# Can't Use System.Web.UI.DataVisualizationt.Charting.Chart Class in c# MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I am probably a fool because I can not find a solution to my problem that seems basic.
I tried different solutions retrieved on the web but without success
On vs2013: I can not integrate the `System.Web.DataVisualization.Design` assembly into a C # MVC project and then use the class chart included in the `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization` namespace.

For my tests I created a new MVC project using FrameWork .net 4.5.1
I added the `System.Web.DataVisualization.Design` assembly using the Add References dialog.

[image: example]

When I create an action result in my controller I add the using statement but this is not enough

"The type or namespace name 'xxxxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

[image: example]
Without solution, I call for help

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Can you translate the error message in English and share it here?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add System.Web.DataVisualization into references